# SQL Server : lower camelcase for each result

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I am creating an API with SQL Server as the database. My tables and columns are using Pascal case (`CountryId`, `IsDeleted`, etc) that cannot be changed.

So when I do this:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
var sqlstr =
'select * from Country where CountryId = @countryId';
var db = await koaApp.getDb();
let result = await db.request()
  .input('countryId', mssql.Int, countryId)
  .query(sqlstr);
```

My resulting object is

```
{
    CountryId: 1,
    CountryName: "Germany"
}
```

But I want it to be

```
{
    countryId: 1,
    countryName: "Germany"
}
```

I know there is a "row" event, but I wanted something more performant (since I may be returning several rows from the query, above is just an example).

Any suggestions?

PS: I want to avoid the `FOR JSON` syntax

Comment: if it's viable, you may try simply specifying the columns in the query as such: `select CountryID countryId, CountryName countryName from Country where CountryId = @countryId `  Typically it's not best practice to use * within queries anyways because of performance.

Comment: @user2366842 that was the answer! I did SELECT countryId, countryCode ... and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this as an actual answer, as it proved helpful to the OP:

if it's viable, you may try simply specifying the columns in the query as such:

```
select 
    CountryID countryId,  
    CountryName countryName 
from 
    Country 
where 
    CountryId = @countryId
```

Typically it's not best practice to use `select *` within queries anyways because of performance.

A simple explanation, putting a space and a new name (or perhaps better practice, within square brackets after each column name, such as `CountryName [countryName]` - this allows for characters such as spaces to be included within the new names) is aliasing the name with a new name of your choosing when returned from SQL.

Comment: indeed. In the case of Sql Server that is case insensitive I pulled it off without the alias. So the syntax is shorter, yet you achieve the same. Probably in other RDBMS you will need the aliases

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using the lodash utility library to convert the column names, there is a _.camelCase function for this:

[CamelCase documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#camelCase)

```
_.camelCase('Foo Bar');
// => 'fooBar'

_.camelCase('--foo-bar--');
// => 'fooBar'

_.camelCase('__FOO_BAR__');
// => 'fooBar'
```

You can enumerate the result keys using Object.entries then do a reduce, e.g.

```js
let result = {
    CountryId: 1,
    CountryName: "Germany"
};
let resultCamelCase = Object.entries(result).reduce((obj,[key,value]) => {
    obj[_.camelCase(key)] = value;
    return obj;
}, {});

console.log(resultCamelCase);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```