# SQL Server generate camelCase for json automatically (for ex. when using JSON_QUERY)

Tags: sql-server

It is common practice that with json the field names are in camel case.

For example: If a field was named 'ThisField' in json it would be 'thisField'

With SQL Server's [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) how can SQL Server be configured to return fields in camel case ?

For ex.

```
SELECT JSON_QUERY((
    SELECT *
    FROM MyColumn
    FOR JSON PATH
))
```

With the above query there is a column that is named 'ThisField' which should be generated as 'thisField' when the json is produced.

NOTE: I don't want to create column aliases manually, that is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: That would be a very, very bad idea. JSON_QUERY doesn't generate JSON, it *reads* it. It shouldn't change the data in any way.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fair enough but how can SQL Server be configured to generate camel case for field names when producing json ?

Comment: You didn't ask about producing JSON, you asked about *reading* JSON. Ask what you really want, what you tried, and why you don't just specify the names you want in the `FOR JSON` clause?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ok, now that you have enlightened me, the underlying question is regarding generating camel case for field names when producing json

Comment: Ask the question, *in the question body*. I can't guess what you tried, or what column aliases you used. Did you check the documentation of the `FOR JSON` clause?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server : lower camelcase for each result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53949006/sql-server-lower-camelcase-for-each-result)

Comment: JSON_QUERY is for *reading*. It doens't produce JSON. `FOR JSON` produces JSON. If you want the column names to appear a certain way, don't use `*`, write the columns with the aliases you want. That's not even JSON-specific, that's how SQL, the language works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos You seem angry. I think there is no bad intent in the question asked. Maybe the OP is not as experienced as you are.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos stop and listen, my question is regarding configuring SQL Server to produce camel case. I know about generating aliases but that is a manual process that can get tedious.

Comment: There's no such thing. It's the *query* that configures how the results look. That's why I said `SQL, the language`. That `*` means `all columns as they are`

Comment: The short answer is no - there is configuration option or runtime option to do what you want. Your naming convention determines the content. You want camel-case? Then define your schema that way or use a tool or write more-complex tsql that will dynamically generate the query to produce the results you want.

Comment: Generating the aliases is trivial anyway, just select the subquery and hit `Ctrl+Q`. The query designer will convert `*` into explicit columns.

Comment: It's a shame there is isn't configuration option. Inside a JSON_QUERY expression it is possible to specify options with FOR JSON, for example there is a ROOT option where it will inject a field name you specify. Perhaps in the future that can be expanded to include a camelCase option.  Anyway thanks for the info everyone.